# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-x^n \arctan(\frac1x)) dx,n>1$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

The following integral $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-x^n \arctan(\frac1x)) dx$ seems converges for all  integer $n>1$ according to sum computation that i runs with wolfram alpha such that it's value are decreasing the max is for $ n=2$  close to $1.18$ and for $n=3$ it's close to $1$,$\cdots$  , because we have the composition of $\exp$ and $\tan^{-1}$   is decreasing function , Using the series representation of $\tan^{-1}(\frac1x)$ which is defined as ::$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{1+2k}(\frac1x)^{1+2k}}{1+2k}$ and by substitution in the titled integral w'd give a  complicated integral which is not easy to get it's closed form , Since this is the case i should ask about:$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-x^n \arctan(\frac1x)) dx$ for $n >1$  without using it's closed form  ?

Comment: Suppose you knew you could take the limit under the integral sign. What would be the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Split the intergal into integral over $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. The inetegrand is increasing in the first interval and decreasing in the second. Since the intergal is finite for $n=1$ we can take the limit inside in both cases and the answer is $1$.